# how to install module "qpoases" for python 3 in linux ? (Quadratic Programming package)

Tags: python, linux

Is there a way to install qpoases for python 3 in linux?

I have used this link instruction [enter link description here](https://projects.coin-or.org/qpOASES/wiki/QpoasesInstallation), but I haven some error during installation.

my result in terminal :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc99G.png)

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove .o file and run the `make` command again.

*PS: Keep in mind to post raw text output rather than images.*

Answer (score 0):

Run following from the root directory.

`cmake .`

`sudo make install`